# Php Script For Registration

Tags: php, mysql

i have a problem with my php registration's  script.
This is my code:

```
    <?php

//response è un array
$response = array();
//response con chiave success, ha valore -1
$response["success"] = -1;



/*ci colleghiamo al database(attenti perchè se lavorate in locale 
l'host è 10.0.2.2 e non 127.0.0.1)*/
 mysql_connect("localhost","fbaprova","")
    or die("Impossibile connettersi al server MySQL.\n"); 
//selezioniamo il db a cui ci vogliamo connettere
mysql_select_db("my_fbaprova")
    or die("Impossibile aprire il database.\n");
//creo la tabella nel database
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_fbaprova`.`Utente` (
            `Ut_Id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `Ut_Username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
            `Ut_Email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
            `Ut_Password` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
            `Ut_PartiteVinte` INT NOT NULL,
            `Ut_PartitePerse` INT NOT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`Ut_Id`))
         ENGINE = InnoDB;"); 
//inserisco i dati  nell'array post
$Ut_Username = $_POST['Ut_Username'];
$Ut_Email = $_POST['Ut_Email'];
$Ut_Password = $_POST['Ut_Password'];
$Ut_PartiteVinte = $_POST['Ut_PartiteVinte'];
$Ut_PartitePerse = $_POST['Ut_PartitePerse'];

//usarlo per la registrazione
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `my_fbaprova`.`Utente` 
                        ( `Ut_Username`, `Ut_Email`,`Ut_Password` , `Ut_PartiteVinte`, `Ut_PartitePerse`) 
                        VALUES ($Ut_Username, $Ut_Email, $Ut_Password, $Ut_PartiteVinte,      $Ut_PartitePerse;");

if($result){

 // success
 $response["success"]= 1;
}else{
 //insuccess
 $response["success"] = -1;
}


// il response sarà = 1 se i dati sono stati inseriti, altrimenti sarà uguale a -1 nel caso l'username o l'email sia già presente nel db
echo json_encode($response);


mysql_close();

    ?>
```

But when i simulated A post with Postman application, from chrome store, the result is always success =-1.

as you'll see, i've not many experience with php.
However, with this code, the table is created , in my db.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the unwanted semicolon from insert query

```
  $Ut_PartitePerse;");
```

And your variables should have been wrapped with single quote like

```
 '$Ut_PartitePerse'
```

So your insert query should be like

```
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO `my_fbaprova`.`Utente` 
                    ( `Ut_Username`, `Ut_Email`,`Ut_Password` , `Ut_PartiteVinte`, `Ut_PartitePerse`) 
                    VALUES ('$Ut_Username', '$Ut_Email', '$Ut_Password', '$Ut_PartiteVinte', '$Ut_PartitePerse')";
```

Comment: Thanks, i add the single quote, and add the end bracket before the semicolon, and success= 1 appeared .

Comment: But there is a text editor for php which makes you noticed these things?